# Showing WPFHidden window using windowHandle

Tags: c#, wpf, window-handles

I have created one WPF window and added some control to it.
Now I will get the window handle and hide the window.

I'll create separate application (console) and use the same `windowHandle`
to show the window using below api

```
[DllImport("User32")]

private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int nCmdShow);
```

but the issue is the window is coming with the black background. Not showing the control.

Can anyone help how to get it done.
(Showing WPF window using window handle)

WPF window Code

```
var windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
int tempHandle = (int)windowInteropHelper.Handle;
string filePath = @"C:\windowHandleLog.txt";
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.Delete(filePath);
}
File.AppendAllText(filePath, tempHandle.ToString());
this.Hide();
```

Console Application Code:

```
string filePath = @"C:\windowHandleLog.txt";
string handle = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
int windowHandle = Convert.ToInt32(handle);
ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
```

[Wpf Window Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep0cC.png)

[Wpf Window After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxgIE.png)

Comment: can you put some code?

Comment: WPF window code:

var windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            int tempHandle = (int)windowInteropHelper.Handle;
            string filePath = @"C:\windowHandleLog.txt";
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, tempHandle.ToString());
            this.Hide();

Comment: Console application code:

string filePath = @"C:\windowHandleLog.txt";
            string handle = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            int windowHandle = Convert.ToInt32(handle);
            SendMessage((IntPtr)windowHandle, WmPaint, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

            ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);

Comment: Agarwal you can use edit section ,,,,,,It will increase readability

Comment: Hi Vikash updated the content. Hope it will give the clear picture what is the issue

Comment: is their any issue if you directly pass handle in showWindow

Comment: Directly means: both are a different application

Comment: Instead of trying to force a different program's window to show externally, maybe used named pipes to send a message to that program and have it show the window itself.

Comment: The main thread of a WPF app requires Application.Run(), that seems to be missing here.  Remove the this.Hide() call and make sure the app works correctly, rendering and responding to input as expected.  Don't use a worker thread to create the window.

Comment: I got the answer in Wpf application instead of using

this.Hide();
I have to use 
ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);